# square validation not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

My validation to check if a file I load into the program is a square or not is not working and I am not sure why and would like some assistance+guidance and explanation so that I can learn.

The problem is to load a file into python and then check if the file is a nxn square.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Code:

```
while True:
    try: 
        filesname = input("Enter the filename:") + ".txt"
        file = open(filesname,"r")
        readFile = file.readlines()
        file.close()
        print ("File has:")
        thelist = []
        square(thelist)
        for line in readFile: 
                thelist.append(line) 
            print (line, end="")
        square(thelist)


    except: 
        print ("The file name you have entered does not exist. Please try again.")
    except:
        print ("")
        print ("Incorrect file format")
    else:
        break
```

I got it working, but when I run the program I get:

```
File contents:
---------------
ABC
BAC
CAB
LJ
Incorrect file format
Enter the filename:
```

This works, however how do I change the program so that It doesn't even print the file out if it isn't in correct format? I've tried playing around with it and can't figure it out.

Comment: You aren't taking new lines into account.  Change `thelist.append(line)` to `thelist.append(line.strip())`.

Comment: Also you're not doing anything with the result of the `square(thelist)` function call. It returns a result and you ignore it.

Comment: @zondo ty, does .strip() just make it read through every line? (just want to know sorry to annoy).

Comment: @PeterGibson so instead of the return False or return True should I have something like raise ValueError?

Comment: `.strip()` removes the whitespace (extra spaces, tabs, newlines, etc.) from both edges of the line.

Comment: @zondo ty. I also ran into another problem and was wondering if you could help point me in the right direction? I've tried to put the function call before it prints but not working.

Comment: You mean before it prints "File has:"?

Comment: @zondo yes, and then it would raise the exception and ask the user to enter the name of another file and not print ABC etc

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `square()` before you print it:

```
while True:
    try: 
        filesname = input("Enter the filename:") + ".txt"
        file = open(filesname,"r")
        readFile = file.readlines()
        file.close()
        thelist = [line.strip() for line in readFile]
        square(thelist)
        print ("File has:")
        print("\n".join(thelist))


    except FileNotFoundError: 
        print ("The file name you have entered does not exist. Please try again.")
    except ValueError:
        print ("")
        print ("Incorrect file format")
    else:
        break
```

Comment: I tried it and it works and I'm comparing it to my old code and I have some questions (apologies if im frustrating you). Does "thelist = [line.strip() for line in readFile]" combine the for loop I had and just make it easier to read? Also what does .join(thelist)) do? (again so sorry lol)

Comment: Hey, that's how we learn.  (Also, I happen to love feeling knowledgeable ;)  `thelist = [line.strip() for line in readFile]` is called [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).  It creates a list of stripped `readFile` lines.  `"\n".join(thelist)` puts a newline between each element in `thelist`.  For example, `"\n".join(["this", "that"])` results in `"this\nthat"`.  `"\n".join(["fa", "li", "jk"])` results in `"fa\nli\njk"`.

Comment: thanks for taking your time to explain everything. I can see by your reputation that everyone elses also does. helped a lot.